# How to configure Spring Boot with elasticsearch 5.2.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to connect my Spring Boot application to local elasticsearch 5.2.1 instance. When i use "**org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch**" dependency, i face with "**Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]**". I think this is due to elasticsearch version is 2.4.4 in starter dependency. So to solve this error, i edit pom.xml properties by adding **elasticsearch.version>5.2.1/elasticsearch.version>** line. But this time i get
"**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.builder()**"

To overcome this issue, i create custom config class like below:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

@Bean
public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    return client;
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
}
```

This time i get apache.logging.log4j exceptions ([check here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/issue-with-elastic-search-5-0-0-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-logging-log4j-core-async-daemonthreadfactory/64345/8)) so i add necessary dependencies.

Finally i get below error and stucked there. Could anyone help me out with this?

**nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/elasticsearch/action/count/CountRequestBuilder**

Answer (score 4):

The github page of [spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) shows that it currently supports elasticsearch only up to version 2.4.0.

For now you have 3 options:

- Wait and hope
- checkout the [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/170)
- checkout the dev branch 5.0.x-prep

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Spring Boot 2. Check out my [spring-boot-elasticsearch-5.x](https://github.com/JahnelGroup/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-elasticsearch-5.x) example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use elasticsearch java api to create transport client instead of using spring-data-elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and getting that error too for `CountRequestBuilder`, reason is that `CountRequestBuilder` class is deprecated and removed now from 5.x elastic search versions, that class is replaced by `SearchRequestBuilder` but unfortunately `spring-data-elasticsearch` don't provide this even in the latest release of its jar and that `CountRequestBuilder` is used in ElasticSearchTemplate.

I am also looking out for some solution. I will post if able to resolve.