# Elasticsearch integration with Java API and SpringBoot exception

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am having this error at running a simple application which integrates spring-boot with elastic-search. Could you please help me solving this? I am beginner.

I am trying to map some books into ES and be able to print them using client configuration from ES Java API. I am wondering if the versions are not used properly so please see my pom.xml

It says something about `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'es'` which I don't know what means. Also regarding `NoClassDefFoundError` -> `nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=53975:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\honeybee\p2p\ESFR\target\classes;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.9\logback-classic-1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.9\logback-core-1.1.9.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.22\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.22\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-elasticsearch\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.13.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.6\jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.22\slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.22\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.2.2\jna-4.2.2.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\5.6.7\elasticsearch-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\6.6.1\lucene-core-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-analyzers-common\6.6.1\lucene-analyzers-common-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-backward-codecs\6.6.1\lucene-backward-codecs-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-grouping\6.6.1\lucene-grouping-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-highlighter\6.6.1\lucene-highlighter-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-join\6.6.1\lucene-join-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-memory\6.6.1\lucene-memory-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-misc\6.6.1\lucene-misc-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-queries\6.6.1\lucene-queries-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-queryparser\6.6.1\lucene-queryparser-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-sandbox\6.6.1\lucene-sandbox-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial\6.6.1\lucene-spatial-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial-extras\6.6.1\lucene-spatial-extras-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-spatial3d\6.6.1\lucene-spatial3d-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\lucene\lucene-suggest\6.6.1\lucene-suggest-6.6.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\securesm\1.2\securesm-1.2.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.2\jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\carrotsearch\hppc\0.7.1\hppc-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.7\joda-time-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.6\jackson-core-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-smile\2.8.6\jackson-dataformat-smile-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.8.6\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-cbor\2.8.6\jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\tdunning\t-digest\3.0\t-digest-3.0.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.9\HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.7\log4j-api-2.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\jna\4.4.0-1\jna-4.4.0-1.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\client\transport\5.6.7\transport-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\plugin\transport-netty3-client\5.6.7\transport-netty3-client-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.10.6.Final\netty-3.10.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\locationtech\spatial4j\spatial4j\0.6\spatial4j-0.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\vividsolutions\jts\1.13\jts-1.13.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.7\log4j-core-2.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\plugin\transport-netty4-client\5.6.7\transport-netty4-client-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.13.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.13.Final\netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.13.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.13.Final\netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.13.Final\netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.13.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.13.Final\netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\plugin\reindex-client\5.6.7\reindex-client-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\client\elasticsearch-rest-client\5.6.7\elasticsearch-rest-client-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.2\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.6\httpcore-4.4.6.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpasyncclient\4.1.2\httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore-nio\4.4.5\httpcore-nio-4.4.5.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\plugin\lang-mustache-client\5.6.7\lang-mustache-client-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\com\github\spullara\mustache\java\compiler\0.9.3\compiler-0.9.3.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\plugin\percolator-client\5.6.7\percolator-client-5.6.7.jar;C:\Users\droban\.m2\repository\org\elasticsearch\plugin\parent-join-client\5.6.7\parent-join-client-5.6.7.jar" com.esfr.engine.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2018-02-13 13:04:04.514  INFO 8776 --- [           main] com.esfr.engine.Application              : Starting Application on EN610890 with PID 8776 (C:\honeybee\p2p\ESFR\target\classes started by droban in C:\honeybee\p2p\ESFR)
2018-02-13 13:04:04.518  INFO 8776 --- [           main] com.esfr.engine.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-13 13:04:04.597  INFO 8776 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@641147d0: startup date [Tue Feb 13 13:04:04 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-13 13:04:05.590  INFO 8776 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=mkyongElasticsearchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/esfr/config/MkyongElasticsearchConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]]
2018-02-13 13:04:10.654  WARN 8776 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'es'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder
2018-02-13 13:04:12.301  INFO 8776 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-13 13:04:12.310 ERROR 8776 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'es'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.esfr.engine.Application.main(Application.java:33) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:206) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:992) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestBuilder$SuggestionBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

And here are the dependencies from maven.
    pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>es-fr</groupId>
    <artifactId>es-fr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this the reason but there can be a problem with Spring Boot 1.5.1 and Elasticsearch 5+.

Please, take a look on the version matrix here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix

and here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch

Here you have similar issue:

[How to configure Spring Boot with elasticsearch 5.2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495090/how-to-configure-spring-boot-with-elasticsearch-5-2-1)

and the possible resolution is to use Spring Boot 2:

https://github.com/JahnelGroup/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-elasticsearch-5.x

Comment: I've seen something related before like Spring Boot version is not compatible with the ES version I am using. I will see the links above. Thanks a lot @Piotr